# How to import urls from an apps folder

Tags: python, django

In django is their a way to extend the python path for the entire project to the entire project to look for imports in every directory.

I have my main urls.py in this dir:

```
project/projectname/urls.py
```

I want to import urls.py from an "apps" folder to use in a `include()`.  That is located here:

```
project/apps/myapp/urls.py
```

I have `__init__.py` in all files.  Not sure why, but feeling very rookie right now.
Thanks for any help

Comment: Just curious. Looks like you are using a custom project structure. Why don't stick with a default one made by `startproject`?

Comment: Does `from apps.myapp import urls` work?

Comment: I'm using a different file structure to better organize a large collection of apps.  Unfortunately, I could not get this to work I tried alecxe and Alberts solution to no avail, and will be going back to the default settings for now.  Getting stuff done is more important.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'', include('apps.myapp.urls')),
)
```

Comment: This doesn' work it doesn't recognize the project dir.

Comment: @SimpleSyrup, oops, fixed the path. BTW, is `include('apps.myapp.urls')` still not work? I've just checked your project struct and everything works fine. Take a look [here](http://pastebin.com/BsrD9hJd).